# How to update selection in the QTableView after drag row

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel

I have custom `QTableView` class that shows content of custom model based on `QAbstractItemModel`. In the model I've implemented all needed methods to support changing rows order by DragAndDrop ( using `dropMimeData()`).

But I do not know how to update selection in the view after model (and view) changed.
For example: 
user clicks on the row, it becomes 'selected'; 
user drags this row to other place;
rows are swaps in the model and view;

BUT selection stays on the first selected row.

How model can notify view to change selection?

NOTE: I cant to create additional signals and slots because don't use MOC.

Comment: Take a look at `QItemSelectionModel` documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

1. In function `dropMimeData()` need to use `beginMoveRows()` and `andMoveRows()` around place where data changed.
2. Need to process signal `QAbstractItemModel::rowsMoved` of the model, where we can retrieve index of the target row.